# Passing Parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to make a "function selectbox(e)", but I need to pass more arguments than the argument (e) I need "function selectbox(e, Name, ID, Row, Col)", how should I define the function and how should I call the function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to pass more than one argument but inside only one parameter.

You can create an object to do that, like:

```
var param = {e: document.getElementById("SomeID")
            ,Name: "Example"
            ,ID: "SomeID"};
selectBox(param);
```

Inside your function you access the arguments as an attribute of an object, you can either define default values in case you don't pass some value:

```
function selectBox(p) {
    p      = p      || {};
    p.e    = p.e    || "";
    p.Name = p.Name || "";
    p.ID   = p.ID   || null;
    p.Row  = p.Row  || 5;
    p.Col  = p.Col  || 20;
    alert("this is the ID: "+p.ID);
}
```

Hope I was clear.